A better way to use Storyblok and fetch data
I am using Next.js 14 App router with StoryBlok CMS.
I have this code and I have to fetch all those urls in Storyblok. But everytime I do this I have to call 3 times the API from the free tier for Storyblok. Is there a way to call only once all 3 story in one fetch?


Here`s my code
const getLandingPageData = async (lang) => {
  const version = process.env.SB_DATA_VERSION;
  const token = process.env.SB_TOKEN;

  const landingPageUrl = `https://api-ca.storyblok.com/v2/cdn/stories/landing-page?version=${version}&token=${token}&language=${lang}`;
  const FaqUrl = `https://api-ca.storyblok.com/v2/cdn/stories/faq?version=${version}&token=${token}&language=${lang}`;
  const ContactUrl = `https://api-ca.storyblok.com/v2/cdn/stories/contacts?version=${version}&token=${token}&language=${lang}`;

  let req = await fetch(landingPageUrl,  { next: { revalidate: 10 } })
  let req2 = await fetch(FaqUrl,  { next: { revalidate: 10 } })
  let req3 = await fetch(ContactUrl,  { next: { revalidate: 10 } })
}

